# External CSS is not working

Tags: html, css

I am using external CSS for some style ,
my link tag is as follow ,

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css2/form.css" rel="stylsheet" TYPE="text/css">
```

the CSS file has following content

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

legend {
padding: 0;
margin-top:-20px;
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right:-40px;
margin-bottom: -9px;
border: 0;
color: #999999;
background-color: #918D8D;
}


.input-group{
margin-left:15px;
}
```

and I used these classes in jsp as follow,

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="dob" class="control-label col-xs-4">Date Of
                        Birth(DOB) :</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 input-group date form_date1" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy"  data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control " size="10" name="dob" id="date" ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

why it is not working , here i am trying to add margine to text box.

Comment: Right click and do 'view source', you can click the link to see if it finds the page

Comment: a dot is missing in your css.
it should be `.legend` instead of `legend`

Comment: ya I checked it s finding the css file . .

Comment: legend is working fine i want to apply it for text box . .

Comment: The . represents a style for a class, he hasn't used class = 'legend', when you don't use the . it applies to all tags with the tag 'legend'

Comment: as far as i can see you are not using any of the css classes in the html you've provided.. then what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Your textbox doesn't have a 15px margin because it's class is 'form-control', if you want the 15px margin you should change the form-control to input-group

Comment: not working means margin is not applying . . If I do it same by inline the margin is applying .

Comment: @Jessica text box is input control rt, but  If I do it inline the margin is applying.

Comment: Do any of the other CSS styles work?

Comment: no this is the first css I am trying but I am using bootstrap , so that is all working fine . .

Comment: Y it s down voted  . ., this s the problem I am facing  . .

Comment: Sorry but I still stand by what I said, the textbox class property does not match the CSS tag, I don't know the reason otherwise, never used bootstrap

Comment: So you want to apply css **input-group** to your textbox. am I right ?

Comment: have a look at my answer. don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which css you want to apply to your textbox. But if you want to apply **input-group** to your textbox then update your input tag as mentioned below :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-group" size="10" name="dob" id="date" ">
```

and apply **!important** to the margin of css **input-group** as mentioned below :

```
.input-group{
     margin-left:15px !important;
}
```

Comment: if I do like this I ll get textbox within a text box . .

Comment: if you do like this, you will be able to apply margin as you asked in question.